# Web scrape html lines based on background color?

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

I am currently new to web scraping with Python. As shown belong is sample HTML code.

```
<div class="bb-fl" style="background:Tomato;width:0.63px" title="10">​</div>,
<div class="bb-fl" style="background:SkyBlue;width:0.19px" title="3">​</div>,
<div class="bb-fl" style="background:Tomato;width:1.14px" title="18">​</div>,
<div class="bb-fl" style="background:SkyBlue;width:0.19px" title="3">​</div>,
<div class="bb-fl" style="background:Tomato;width:1.52px" title="24">​</div>,
```

I would like to use beautifulsoup to find lines with the same class (bb-fl) and ONLY return lines which have: style="background:SkyBlue"

Currently I have figured out how to return all HTML code lines that have the "bb-fl" class with the following line.

```
soup.find_all('div',{'class':'bb-fl'})
```

Answer (score 1):

You might achieve that by using some regex logic here :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """<div class="bb-fl" style="background:Tomato;width:0.63px" title="10">​</div>,
<div class="bb-fl" style="background:SkyBlue;width:0.19px" title="3">​</div>,
<div class="bb-fl" style="background:Tomato;width:1.14px" title="18">​</div>,
<div class="bb-fl" style="background:SkyBlue;width:0.19px" title="3">​</div>,
<div class="bb-fl" style="background:Tomato;width:1.52px" title="24">​</div>,"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

#Find all divs which style attribute contains ...
soup.find_all('div', style = re.compile("background:SkyBlue"))
```

Result :

```
[<div class="bb-fl" style="background:SkyBlue;width:0.19px" title="3">​</div>,
 <div class="bb-fl" style="background:SkyBlue;width:0.19px" title="3">​</div>]
```

It will work whatever the other style values might be.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following according to the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attrs)

```
soup.find_all('div', attrs={'style':'background:SkyBlue'})
```

Comment: That did not work for me. Though when I list the exact width, it works.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
bbfls = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'bb-fl'})
for bbfl in bbfls:
    if "background:SkyBlue" in bbfl.attrs.get("style"):
        print(bbfl.attrs)
```

If you want it in a single line try this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
print([bbfl.attrs for bbfl in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'bb-fl'}) if "background:SkyBlue" in bbfl.attrs.get("style")])
```

Output

```
{'class': ['bb-fl'], 'style': 'background:SkyBlue;width:0.19px', 'title': '3'}
{'class': ['bb-fl'], 'style': 'background:SkyBlue;width:0.19px', 'title': '3'}
```

Comment: If you down vote an answer, please specify why? This is a different approach from the one above and also works, absolutely no reason to down vote it